# Unable to click anchor tag(tel) with javascript on chrome for android

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tel

I have a requirement to trigger click event on an anchor tag with tel href. It is working fine for firefox and safari mobile browsers but does not work on chrome for android.

[This is what I tried with USB debugging mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpr1I.png)

As you can see in the image, I was getting this error:

> Navigation is blocked: tel:+919898989898

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong and how can I accomplish it.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?